# Difference between two Objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use OpenStreetMap API. In the docs, we have an example Object :

```
var villes = {
            "Dijon": { "lat": 47.3215806, "lon": 5.0414701 },
            "Montbard": { "lat": 47.6241674, "lon": 4.3373194 }
        };
```

Now I would like to replace this static object by a dynamic object, assigned dynamically in a loop and each iteration is added to the object with Object.assign()

In result, the Object looks well formated but it doesn't work. The only difference I can see is in console. What is the difference between them ? I couldn't understand. (the first one looks empty but values are well stored. The second is working and it's the static one)

[image]

---

EDIT : code added below

Here is the code where the dynamic object is built :

```
var mesvilles = {};
        var ville_current = {};

        for (let i=0; i < cities.length; i++){
            $.getJSON('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q='+cities[i]+'&country=France&format=json', function(data) {

                ville_current = {[cities[i]]: {"lat": parseFloat(data[0].lat), "lon": parseFloat(data[0].lon)}};
                mesvilles = Object.assign(mesvilles,ville_current);
            });
        }
        console.log(mesvilles);
```

Here is the original Object:

```
var villes = {
            "Dijon": { "lat": 47.3215806, "lon": 5.0414701 },
            "Montbard": { "lat": 47.6241674, "lon": 4.3373194 }
        };
        console.log(villes);
```

Comment: Can you post the full code that includes where you console.log? Looks like the first time you log, the object is empty

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Imagine someone telling you : "My code doesn't work, what's the solution?", what do you reply?

Comment: Are you trying to compare them but get that they are unequal?

Comment: When you say "static", do you mean "constant"?

Comment: Code added. Thanks. Well, the idea is mostly to understand why the objects look differents, if they are

Comment: Wrap your code in a promise and proceed on then method with your transformation this is an async issue

Comment: He uses a callback fn @PanosK

Comment: Here is how I would do it without a promise. Using async await is more elegant

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it was obviously an async issue. I didn't think about that. I never asked for a debug (and answer to the "it doesn't work" question, please read carefully). Thank you for all your suggestions